# Host name does not match the certificate subject in deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Facing an issue with the below error reason in kubernetes deployment for the HTTPS Certificate

> **Error :**  Host name does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=customer.endpoint.com)

My application is running with Network ip address with port number. Network ip is dynamic for the pods. So how do we alias customer.endpoint.com to avoid the above issue

Comment: What is the CN for the SSL which already installed in kubernetes. It seems DNS name and SSL certs domain name mismatched. Can you check on this site ? if SSL is correctly installed or not ? https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Comment: Please share more information about your architecture, where is the HTTPS client: inside/outside the cluster? Do you have any Ingress or LB for incoming traffic, what are their settings? What are the certificate configuration: CN, SAN? What is the deployment YAML? Where this error came from? The more related details you put, the better answer you can get.

Answer (score 0):

To access your application first you have to  create service for it. Read more here: [kubernetes-services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

Then you have to  create a TLS certificate for a Kubernetes service accessed through DNS.
Please take a look at [tls-certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/). In this documentation you will find how to properly set up certificates.

The flow will be like:

**1.** Create service to expose you app - for example `ClusterIP`.
Remember that choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default `ServiceType`

**2.**  Download and install CFSSL - source: [pkg-cfssl](https://pkg.cfssl.org/).

**3.** Create a Certificate Signing Request

**4.**  Create a Certificate Signing Request object to send to the Kubernetes API

**5.** Get the Certificate Signing Request Approved

**6.** Download the Certificate and use it